# edit expression in visual studio

Tags: visual-studio-2005, ssrs-2008, reportingservices-2005

Anyone knows what language one can use when editing an expression (SSRS expressions) in visual studio? Also, if possible would like to have a link to a documentation or a tutorial for that language.

Comment: An expression? What kind of expression?

Comment: In the layout tab you have the option of right clicking on your text field and choosing expression...
There you can edit your expression for that text field and I am wondering what language is used there.

Comment: Layout tab? What layout tab? What technolgoy/language are you writing in?

Comment: The layout tab that I am talking about is in the design view. I am using visual studio 2005.

Comment: Visual Studio 2005 is an IDE. What language are you using? C++? VB.NET? C#? Something else? What kind of project is this? Web? Winforms? WPF? Something else?

Comment: I am using t-sql to generate data and I use that to populate tables in my report.

Comment: OK. We seem to be getting somewhere. Is this a SQL Server Reporting Services report?

Comment: That is the kind of detail that you should have put in the question (or a tag at a minimum).

Comment: Okay I see. I just don't think it's relevant to the question.

Comment: It is relevant if you want people to know what you are talking about. "an expression in visual studio" is like saying "a paragraph in a text file". Without more context, it is meaningless.

Comment: Oded I am not trying to rude or anything but can you answer my question or not. Also, do you speak Hebrew?

Comment: I can't answer the question, but I am trying to help you with formulating a question that someone else _can_.

Comment: As for Hebrew, however off-topic that is, yes, I am a native Hebrew speaker.

Comment: lol! Ahen ahen. P.S. Leazazel im ha VS haze. Eh ze nafal alai ein li musag.

Comment: btw: knowing that I use SSRS will make the question more clear?

Comment: Absolutely. Without knowing the project type one can assume you are talking about the layout tab for winforms, WPF or webforms in addition to reports...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In an expression, the language is whatever the expression builder supports.  Sort of a blend of Excel and Access syntax.

It's also possible to add code to the Report -> Report Properties -> Code window.  In that window, the syntax is more like VBScript or VB6.  Functions built there, can be accessed from an expression:

```
=Code.MyFunction(someParameter)
```

According to http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms155798(v=sql.90).aspx, the language is provided by several .NET 2.0 assemblies Microsoft.VisualBasic, System.Convert, and System.Math.